# FAST thumbnails not showing up when search is displayed inside an iFrame

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, search, fast-search

When I make a search via FAST directly in the browser, my docx and pptx files appear with a thumbnail image. I can even preview pptx documents in the search page.

However, **when I show the search results in an iFrame** (the user inputs the query parameters in a page and I get the SharePoint search results using query string parameters), I can see the search results, but **no thumbnails**, nor preview in browser... This happens in all browsers.

What sorcery is this? The URLs are exactly the same.

Comment: Is the protocol the same? Are you referring http instead of https maybe?

Comment: @HughWood: http in both cases. It's not even possible to reach the SharePoint site via https.

Comment: There is a weird bug sometimes with iframes, absolute paths don't work. This is a browser issue. See if you use the relative path to the image does it work? (Best to test with firebug, add the javascript version to IE to debug) in general it will strongly help you with debugging the situation. I will do some investigation.

Comment: @HughWood I notice that when I do a search, the search results are presented without images and only then the images "pop up". I assume some kind of Javascript is involved... **My "surrounding" page and the SharePoint server are in completely different domains.** Not even subdomains. Do browsers have some kind of policy that might be preventing some of the Javascript to run? I think not.

Comment: Chrome has the best tool to check what's going on. It's javascript profiler will record everything that goes on, time it and check what is effected by what. Click on the iframe hit f12, then refresh with the profiler turned on. I am still leaning towards absolute vs relative URLs. The only other thing is, are you displaying the iframe with Javascript? There are cases where javascript won't run and images won't load in Javascript rendered iframes.

Comment: @HughWood No, I'm not using Javascript to display the iFrame. Pure HTML.